# How to force program to recognize word and stop

Tags: c, variables

I have a problem related to different types of variables at the input type.
My program is simple. I type the temperature in Celsius, program prints Celsius and Fahrenheit temperature value and then loops itself asking for next value in Celsius. If you type "-99999" it will stop.
I wanted to change it to stop when I type a word "elo" (It basically means "Bye" in Polish slang :) ) but after a few hours of trying I gave up...
I'll appreciate any help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

float fahrenheit(long);

int main()
{
    int celsius;
    printf("Type the temperature in celsius: ", &celsius);
    scanf_s("%ld", &celsius);

    while (celsius != -99999) {
        printf("%ld %6.1f\n", celsius, fahrenheit(celsius));
        printf("Type the temperature in celsius: ", &celsius);
       scanf_s("%ld", &celsius);
    }
}

float fahrenheit(long celsius)
{
    return (float) 1.8*celsius + 32.0;
}
```

Comment: You will have to read in your input as a string, compare it to `elo` and if not `elo`, convert it to to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this.  I think the easiest is to detect `scanf` failed to read a number and then fall back on string input.

```
int celcius;
char buff[10];
bool elo = false;

int args_read = scanf(" %d", &celcius);
if (args_read < 1) {
    // User must have put in a non-number
    scanf(" %s", buff);

    if (strcmp(buff, "elo") == 0) {
        elo = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: but temperatures can be less than 1, how can that be fixed? and can we do this with `cin` ?

Comment: This code should work find if the temperature is less than 1.  `args_read` is not the temperature, it's a number indicating whether `scanf` succesfully read the expected integer or not.  As for `cin`, I recommend using C-style input processing because C++'s way of doing it is so bad

Comment: Okay I will remember that! Now... what term is used to refer to returning-of-values-by-scanf?

Comment: The return value of scanf is one of those things everyone ignores when they really shouldn't.

Comment: yes and i knew a few cases they are needed but i was ignorant so i asked straightaway without any effort

Comment: Thank you for your comment as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

The line `printf("Type the temperature in celsius: ", &celsius);` is strange. Didn't your compiler complain about this? Why are you providing the address of `celsius` as an argument to this call? Another mistake is `scanf_s("%ld", &celsius);`, which reads in `celsius` as a `long int` value, when you have only declared `celsius` as an `int`. It's a good idea to always enable compiler warnings when you're working on code.

As mentioned by [@StephenDocy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9264702/stephen-docy), you need to read in the input as a string first, then check to see if it is a number or your stop word.

You can also simplify your code a bit to avoid repeating lines like `printf("Type the temperature in celsius: ", &celsius);` more than necessary. I think it would also make sense to treat `celsius` as a floating point value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

float fahrenheit(float);

int main() {
    float celsius;
    char input_buffer[256];

    while (1) {
        printf("Type the temperature in celsius:\n");
        scanf("%255s", input_buffer);
        if (strcmp("elo", input_buffer) == 0) break;
        if (sscanf(input_buffer, "%f", &celsius) == 1) {
            printf("%6.1f %6.1f\n", celsius, fahrenheit(celsius));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

float fahrenheit(float celsius) {
    return 1.8 * celsius + 32.0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank You for you complex answer, it really helped me a lot :)
I know that '&celsius' seems to be wrong but Visual is not complaining at all... strange. Instead, when I delete "&" symbol it starts going crazy telling me that "Uninitialized local variable "celsius" used" but as You can see I have put it in main function as it should be... don't know why that happens